# Necessary conditions for being zero in the tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R\in \mathbf{CRing}$, and let $M,N$ be $R$-modules. Suppose that $m\otimes n\in M\otimes N$ is (in the equivalence class of) zero.

Looking at the page of Wikipedia, it looks like the only chance for $m\otimes n$ to be in relation with another element is either $m=rm'$ or $n=r'n'$. In the first case $m\otimes n$ is in relation with $m'\otimes rn$, in the other with $r'm\otimes n'$. So in order for $m\otimes n$ to be $0$ either $\operatorname{Ann} m$ or $\operatorname{Ann} n$ is non-empty.

Are there any other remarkable necessary conditions that a zero element in the tensor product has to satisfy?